# Getting error in taking command line arguments in python

Tags: python

I am using windows with python2.7. My program is quite simple. Taking an input via command line and checking if it is '5'.

Code:

```
import unittest
import sys

a=sys.argv[1]

print a

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """My tests"""

    def test_is_number_is_five(self):
        self.assertEqual('5',a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And running it using:

```
>>python test.py 5
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 130, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 100, in loadTestsFromName
    parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '5'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`unittest.main()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) will obtain a list of tests to run from the command line. Hence it is trying to find a test named `5` in your module, but it fails because there is no such test.

To work around the problem you can pass your own `argv` values to `unittest.main()`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(argv=sys.argv[:1])
```

This passes only the first argument, which is the script file name. It does, however, break some the functionality of `unittest.main()` should you want to pass test names on the command line.